# how to convert csv list of decimal to binary

Tags: python, csv

I have a big amount of decimal number in CSV file that I need to convert it to binary.
I tread Excel with `=DEC2BIN($$)`, but it only got me to 511 decimal.
I also found the following python def and my question is there anyway to import a CSV list and convert it to binary and then export it back to CSV ?

```
def dec2bin(number: int):
    ans = ""
    if ( number == 0 ):
        return 0
    while ( number ):
        ans += str(number&1)
        number = number >> 1
    
    ans = ans[::-1]

    return ans

def main():
    number = 513
    print(f" {number} - {dec2bin(number)}")

def main():
    number = 514
    print(f" {number} - {dec2bin(number)}")


# driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You can use f-strings and the b format specifier to easily convert integers to their binary representation. The way you handle the CSV file (input and rewrite) will depend on how the CSV data are organised. Maybe you could show a sample of what you have and what you want

Comment: its just list of number from 1 to 1800

Comment: then show an sample of 5 rows

Comment: @ZakMeshou If you know the input data are just a range (1 to 1800), why do you need an input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input CSV has just a single column (no heading) then it's just:

```
with open('input.csv') as indata, open('output.csv', 'w') as outdata:
    for line in indata:
        print(f'{int(line):b}', file=outdata)
```

Comment: That just did it for me, thank you